# Issue with Perl6 panda and p6doc

Tags: document, raku

Question about panda and p6doc.

On Mac, I followed https://perl6.org/downloads/ to install perl6 (as root), but there is no panda. Then I found https://github.com/tadzik/panda and installed panda (as root), but when I ran panda or p6doc (as non-root), there were errors: "Failed to create directory....".

Did i miss something?

Tiger

Comment: You may need to use `sudo` to run panda with the proper privileges.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the Rakudo Star Mac OS X .dmg installer, which includes the compiler, panda, and several useful modules.

http://rakudo.org/downloads/star/ (linked to under "Installing from Binaries")

Comment: .dmg installer:

Comment: .dmg installer does not install panda nor p6doc:

Comment: $ ls /Applications/Rakudo/bin/
moar   nqp-m   perl6-debug-m  perl6-m
nqp   perl6   perl6-gdb-m  perl6-valgrind-m

Comment: Look at the README that comes with it - panda and other utilities are not in the main path.

 3. In a Terminal window add Rakudo Star to your path:
    export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Rakudo/bin:/Applications/Rakudo/share/perl6/site/bin